# Using a Trigger to check that a staff is over 18 from the current date

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to ensure that new staff are over the age of 18, so i figured that the way to do this is to use a trigger that would subtract the staff date of birth from the current date.

This is my table;

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF (
Staff_ID NUMBER(5),
First_Name VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
Last_Name VARCHAR2(25),
Date_Of_Birth DATE NOT NULL,
Gender VARCHAR2(25),
Email VARCHAR2(25),
Telephone NUMBER(15),
Department VARCHAR2(25),
Staff_Type VARCHAR2(25),
Occupation VARCHAR2(25),
Hire_Date DATE,
Salary NUMBER (10)
);
```

This is my Insert statement;

```
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (1,'Ukeme', 'Mfon', TO_DATE('1980-12-2', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Male', 'mfonclals@gmail.com',7826768732, 'Medical Team','Full-time','Nurse', TO_DATE('2023-02-12', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 40000, 1);
```

This is my trigger;

```
create or replace trigger dob_check
before insert on Staff
for each row
declare
minimum_age number := 18;
begin
if extract(year from (sysdate - :old.Date_Of_Birth) year to month) < minimum_age
then
raise_application_error (-20000, 'Minimum age is '||minimum_age);
end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: You have not asked any question so it is unclear what the problem is.

Comment: A better constraint, that doesn't depend on any transient state (such as the current time), would surely be to check their age on the hire date? That could be implemented as a straightforward `CHECK` constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're checking age before inserting a row into the `staff` table, there's no `:old` value there, only `:new`. That's why your trigger did *nothing*.

Simplified:

```
SQL> create table staff (staff_id number, first_name varchar2(10), date_of_birth date);

Table created.
```

See line #7, which references `:new.date_of_birth`:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger dob_check
  2    before insert on staff
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    minimum_age number := 18;
  6  begin
  7    if extract(year from (sysdate - :new.date_of_birth) year to month) < minimum_age then
  8       raise_application_error(-20000, 'Minimum age is ' || minimum_age);
  9    end if;
 10
 11    if :new.date_of_birth > sysdate then
 12       raise_application_error(-20001, 'Person can not be born in the future');
 13    end if;
 14  end;
 15  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into staff(staff_id, first_name, date_of_birth) values
  2    (1, 'Little', date '2014-03-28');
insert into staff(staff_id, first_name, date_of_birth) values
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Minimum age is 18
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.DOB_CHECK", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.DOB_CHECK'


SQL> insert into staff(staff_id, first_name, date_of_birth) values
  2    (1, 'Foot', date '2004-03-28');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: I figured it out after a lot of tries. Thanks a lot for taking out the time to answer.

Comment: Please I have another question. Do you mind if I share the link to it?

Comment: No problem; I'll have a look and assist, if I can.

Comment: it's still in the staging area. But this is what I want to do "I want to implement a trigger to ensure a new date cannot be set beyond or above the current date"

Comment: You can create a new trigger, or add that condition into existing one (as I did); have a look at edited code, lines #11 - 13.

Comment: Here is a link to what I have done so far on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/q/76128319/13451432