# I want to implement a trigger to ensure a new date cannot be set beyond or above the current date

Tags: oracle, plsql

It works well when the date entered is above or beyond the set date by throwing an error. But it still throws an error when the date is exactly the same which is not supposed to be so.

This is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER hire_date_check
before insert or update on Staff
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   minimum_date date := sysdate;
BEGIN
IF :NEW.Hire_date = minimum_date 
END IF;
    
if  :NEW.Hire_Date < minimum_date then
 raise_application_error(-20000, 'cant be below Minimum date' || minimum_date);
end if;

 if :NEW.Hire_Date > minimum_date then
 raise_application_error(-20001, 'cant be Above Minimum date' || minimum_date);
  end if;
END;
/
COMMIT
/
```

Comment: @Littlefoot This is what I have done so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sysdate contains both date **and time**, which means that you should **exactly** match that value during insert into `staff` table, otherwise both `IF`s will fail.

Presuming that people are hired on a *date* (e.g. today is 28.04.2023), without specifying time component (e.g. I was hired today, 28.04.2023 at 11:32:28), then **truncate** sysdate:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER hire_date_check
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON Staff
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   minimum_date  DATE := TRUNC (SYSDATE);         --> this
BEGIN
   IF :NEW.Hire_Date < minimum_date
   THEN
      raise_application_error (-20000, 'cant be below Minimum date' || minimum_date);
   END IF;

   IF :NEW.Hire_Date > minimum_date
   THEN
      raise_application_error (-20001, 'cant be Above Minimum date' || minimum_date);
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: If you're not a genius, I don't see any other word fit. thank you. I am new to SQL but I am a JS developer and I find it very different from what I'm used to. Thank you.