# I want to implement a trigger to ensure a new date cannot be set beyond or above the current date

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to implement a trigger to ensure a new date cannot be set beyond or above the current date. I am having trouble constructing a proper IF ELSE statement to support this logic.

Please help.
This is my table;

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF (
    Staff_ID NUMBER(5),
    First_Name VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    Last_Name VARCHAR2(25),
    Date_Of_Birth DATE NOT NULL,
    Gender VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR2(25),
    Telephone NUMBER(15),
    Department VARCHAR2(25),
    Staff_Type VARCHAR2(25),
    Occupation VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    Hire_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Salary NUMBER (10)
);
```

This is my trigger;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER hire_date_check
before insert or update on Staff
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   minimum_date date := sysdate;
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.Hire_date = minimum_date
    THEN RETURN;

    ELSE
           raise_application_error (-20000, 'hire date cant be in the future '||minimum_date);
 
    END IF;
END;
/
COMMIT
/
```

Comment: [**DATE data type**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5405B652-C30E-4F4F-9D33-9A4CB2110F1B): *For each DATE value, Oracle stores the following information: year, month, day, **hour, minute, and second**.* So `something = sysdate` is almost always is false. You need to check: `trunc(:new.hire_date) = trunc(sysdate)`

Comment: You asked exactly the same question earlier this week. It was answered and marked correct.

Comment: How about `if :new.hire_date > sysdate`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to implement a trigger to ensure a new date cannot be set beyond or above the current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76128319/i-want-to-implement-a-trigger-to-ensure-a-new-date-cannot-be-set-beyond-or-above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you feel that you need a trigger? If the value has to be "today" wouldn't make sense to set a default value for the column?

NOTE: Setting a default value for a column will not affect the existing data in the table.

I create a table with a column dt that has no default value

```
 ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

 create table foo(
      col1 number primary key,
      dt DATE
  );

 insert into foo( col1 ) values (1);
 insert into foo( col1 ) values (2);
 insert into foo( col1 ) values (3);

 select * from foo order by col1;

COL1    DT
1    - 
2    - 
3    -
```

If I then alter the table to set a default value, nothing about the existing rows will change

```
alter table foo modify( dt DATE default TRUNC(SYSDATE));

 select * from foo order by col1;

COL1    DT
1    - 
2    - 
3    -

 insert into foo( col1 ) values (4);

 select * from foo order by col1;

COL1    DT
3    - 
1    - 
2    - 
4   29-APR-2023 00:00:00
```

Even if I subsequently change the default again, there will still be no change to the existing rows

```
alter table foo modify( dt DATE default SYSDATE);

 select * from foo order by col1;

COL1    DT
1    - 
2    - 
3    - 
4   29-APR-2023 00:00:00

 insert into foo( col1 ) values (5);

select * from foo order by col1;

COL1    DT
1    - 
2    - 
3    - 
4   29-APR-2023 00:00:00
5   29-APR-2023 13:21:21
```